# scaleX from center then rotate css

Tags: html, css

How do I apply scaleX transformation on the center then do a rotate? Looking at my CSS I simply do a `transform: scaleX(-1);` to do a horizontal flip. When doing a 180 because I rotate from the center the flip works fine.

However I have no idea how to do it on rotate left and right (HFlipRoR HFlipRoL). I tried making the class "HFlip RoR" but in that case it only applies one of the transformation

Here is my snippet:

```css
.RoR {
  transform: translate(0, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.RoL {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0%) rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}
.R180 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.HFlip {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
.HFlipRoR {
  transform: scaleX(-1) translate(0, -100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
.HFlip180 {
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="HFlipRoR" src="https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3010/4566263938_a56f24a24f.jpg">
```

Comment: I'm not following. In `.HFlipRoR` you want `transform-origin` to apply `translate(0, -100%) rotate(90deg)` and then flip the image in place?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/9f2y5bfb/1/

Comment: @RMo: No. Flip the image than rotate right. Ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGsAj.gif from 1 to 5 and 7. The rest I can do

Comment: @akinuri: see my above comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fhrwL4r0/4/ Is this about what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, and using the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGsAj.gif) you've provided, we can mimic the transformations in the image. Hovering over the numbers will show the corresponding image.

```js
$("#list li").hover(function() {
  $("img").hide();
  $("#_" + this.innerText).show();
}, function() {
  $("img").show();
});
```

```css
#list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: table;
}
#list li {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
#list li:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#list li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
img {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .75;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
#_2 {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
#_3 {
  transform: translate(0, 200%) scale(-1);
}
#_4 {
  transform: translate(0, 200%) scaleY(-1);
}
#_5 {
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%) rotate(90deg) scaleY(-1);
}
#_6 {
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%) rotate(90deg) scale(-1);
}
#_7 {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%) rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
}
#_8 {
  transform: translate(100%, 100%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_1" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_2" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_3" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_4" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_5" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_6" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_7" />
<img src="http://i1115.photobucket.com/albums/k544/akinuri/f.gif" id="_8" />
```

Comment: Didn't help https://jsfiddle.net/oz3b1vw5/ if you try all of them the image has the same X, Y point. The HFlipRoR and HFlipRoL I made from your 5 & 7 puts the image at a different point

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You've provided an image which shows 7 transformations (assuming 1 is the initial state). I've provided transformations which would turn 1 to 2, 3, 4, ... If this is not what you're looking for, you can try to be more clear, maybe  create a graph with MSPaint or PS explaning your desired effect.